# Rich Select with different value but same label is not behaving correctly

Tags: user-interface, jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:select dropdown which has different values but some labels are same.
For example:-(A-a,B-b,C-a,D-a)

So whenever, i'm selecting D-a select item, its submitting A-a, i.e. the first select item with same label.

So the functionality is not working porperly.

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: This has already been fixed, upgrade to the latest version. What's the point of duplicate labels? How does the user which one to select?

Comment: We have tooltip to differentiate different labels. Can you tell me the version after which in which it has been fixed?

Comment: What about changing label from "a" to "A-a", ..., "D-a" ?

Comment: I can't do that. Its customer requirement. Anyways, its fixed in the latest richfaces version(4.5.10).